# Use of PHP in CSS vs Adaption via JS[General]

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have a general question about the use of PHP in CSS.
I am working right now on a Wordpress Theme and would like to make it as customizable as possible.
I therefore sent the CSS Properties I would like to change via PHP to a JS file that changed them for me.
But I am unsure if this is the best way to do it.

Would you guys recommend it and what are the pros and cons?

Comment: Well that's an interesting question.. perhaps this may help you? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950734/change-css-value-with-php ... Also, check this out : http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor/ Perhaps not the most responsive way to do this, but still an interesting way to handle CSS using PHP :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me tell you how I implemented customisable themes on my website, and see if it's of any help to you.

To start with, I use LESS. Wherever I have something customisable (usually colours, but sometimes background images too) I drop in a variable.

Then I have a `_colours.less` file, which simply defines all the variables, and gets imported at the start of every other `.less` file.

Finally, I present the users with an interface to edit these variables in a user-friendly manner.

At run-time, the PHP checks:

- Does the main `core.css` file exist?
- Is the `core.css`'s modification time more recent than the `_colours.less` modification time?
- Are the modification times of all `.css` file being used in this page more recent than the corresponding `.less` file's?

If any of the above result in the answer "no", then the given `.css` file is recompiled on-the-fly using the PHP `lessc` class (that basically implements the LESS compiler).

In this way, users can easily create their own custom themes, but it doesn't interfere in any way with my ability to update the site's layout.

Comment: Do you use any plugins to edit the LESS file or did you code it yourself?

Comment: I now use the exact same approach. Thanks alot. Eventhough I am not using the same PHP Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

sending php value in js may create trouble sometime.

suppose your user install some plugin which js may conflict with your theme's js.
It is possible it stops parsing further js and your changes may not apply.

So according to me setting php value in css is good method.