# java script queries not showing results until temporary internet files deleted

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I have some webpages that make calls to an `SQL` server using `php` and also use `JavaScript` to load dropdown boxes and page content. The problem is that when I use a page to make changes to the SQL database, which works fine, these changes are not reflected in the dropdowns until I delete temporary internet files and refresh the page.

How can I clear the required files so that the data is displayed correctly?

Comment: You need to set proper cache control headers on your responses, so the browser knows it can't cache them (or knows how long it's valid to cache them for).

Comment: Have you specified that the content of those dropdowns should not be cached?  Because it sounds like you're returning content without any cache-control directives, and the browser is (understandably) using its cached local copy to avoid going back to your server, so you're getting the stale data.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths: It's "JavaScript". Not "Java script".

Comment: @Tim Thanks Tim. This is the first time I have done this and therefore small steps. How do I specify that they should not be cached

Comment: That sounds like pretty aggressive caching even without proper headers. Most browsers will fetch a new html page after a few clicks on refresh. Are you using the PHP to generate Javascript files containing the data for your dropdowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the browser from caching your content and then serving that (stale) content up, you can set headers that say that your content shouldn't be stored in caches, which will force the browser to load a clean copy from your server every time the page is loaded, ensuring that up-to-date content is loaded each time.

[How to set HTTP headers (for cache-control)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480304/how-to-set-http-headers-for-cache-control) has info, though you'll want to use NO-CACHE instead of PUBLIC, since that poster was trying to enable caching and you're trying to disable it.  You can do more complicated things if you want (e.g. if you know that your database is only updated once an hour on the hour, you could set cache-control headers that will say that the content can be cached, but only till the end of the hour), but for what you've described, simply disallowing caching seems to be what you want.

I've never done any PHP, but [this page](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-caching-headers/) seems to show how to do the PHP end of it.