# xtreme slow response from apache localhost

Tags: php, macos, apache, localhost

I have a problem with apache2 on localhost and PHP 5.5.8. on Macosx
Everything is installed with Homebrew.

What could be the cause of the delay?
When I want to stop the server, it sometimes responds with

```
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.43.114 for ServerName
```

this is how I set it up

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.dev  
    DocumentRoot "/Users/redres/Webdev/testsetup/public"
    ServerName test.dev
    ServerAlias test.dev
    <Directory "/Users/redres/Webdev/testsetup/public">
       Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
       Options All
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from All
       Header Set Cache-Control no-cache
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/perf-tuning.html << that may or may not be of help

Comment: I know there is a 5 second delay when using a `.local` address for the vhost under macosx, due to some bonjour specific lookup. Seeing as your are not using .local then you would need to provide more info about your problem to get help.

Comment: what do you need, I have a basic install from homebrew, so this is all I have done to set it up, plus the hosts file.

Comment: @Dagon, thanks. I also came across that link and I am reading it. Also, maybe someone here has experienced the same problems when migrating to apache2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling the caching:

```
Header Set Cache-Control public
```

Also give this a read:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480318/3199478

For in-depth reading:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: I will have a look at those links.

Comment: thanks, the caching helped to resolve this issue.