# Control of requested files, how to?

Tags: html, request, twitter-bootstrap-3, phalcon

while playing with a Phalcon tutorial I observed that when navigating it only made one get file request from server event if where inluded more files in HTML.

`http://188.240.2.29:20005/` if you navigate between menus one GET is made only, when refresh  page with F5 additional files are called.

Same thing i observed with other websites: StackOverflow has 9 files called while with F5 there are 29, Reddit normally has 15 files called wile with F5 refresh 35 files are called.

I want to know how this is achieved and how it can be implemented in other websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't about Phalcon itself, but it's about [HTTP Cache](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html). You can read more about it and learn how to implement it [here](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480304/how-to-set-http-headers-for-cache-control) and [here](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/).