# How do i use Cache Control and ETag to set http headers

Tags: caching, joomla, cache-control, pagespeed, etag

I want to use Cache Control and ETag in my joomla website as suggested by google. But have no idea how to do that. I googled it a lot but could not find any worty example.

Can anybody tell me how to do that..??

For Cache Control i have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480304/how-to-set-http-headers-for-cache-control) example, but is this the complete syntax..?? and where to place it in `<head>` tag of the `index.php` file??.

Also please tell me the syntax of ETag and the place where to write it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use your .htaccess file at the root of your website for this. You'll find lots of variations on the specifics, here's a comprehensive one from http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla/joomla-speed.htm#htaccess.

Using a text editor, add the following to your .htaccess file

**EDIT**  If your goal is specifically to improve your YSlow score and you aren't using these tags for any other purpose, it may be better to set the ETag below to:

```
FileETag none
```

Source: https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

```
########## Begin - ETag Optimization
## This rule will create an ETag for files based only on the modification
## timestamp and their size. 
## Note: It may cause problems on your server and you may need to remove it  
## Note: See comments above about why you might want to set the following to FileETag none 
FileETag MTime Size
# AddOutputFilterByType is now deprecated by Apache. Use mod_filter in the future.
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript
# Enable expiration control
ExpiresActive On
# Default expiration: 1 hour after request
ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 hour"
# CSS and JS expiration: 1 week after request
ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 1 week"

# Image files expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresByType image/bmp "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jp2 "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/pipeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/tiff "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.wap.wbmp "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.wap.wbxml "now plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType application/smil "now plus 1 month"
# Audio files expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresByType audio/basic "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/mid "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/midi "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/mpeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/x-aiff "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/x-mpegurl "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/x-pn-realaudio "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/x-wav "now plus 1 month"

# Movie files expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType x-world/x-vrml "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/x-msvideo "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mpeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/quicktime "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/x-la-asf "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/x-ms-asf "now plus 1 month"
```

Alternatively, you will find plenty of extensions which will do a similar thing in the JED
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/cache

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. I tried this script but my site began to distort. I also followed the link, but what i see is my main menu css is not working fine when i turn on the `Conservative caching`. Can you guess what is the problem. I have hosting on BlueHost server, can it be a problem.

Comment: Hi @gsm11001 , caching via the Joomla backend is not exactly the same as what I described above. Using .htaccess you are telling the browser that it doesn't need to redownload an image or a CSS file if it already has a copy which isn't more than a week (or a month) old... whatever you specified in .htaccess. With Joomla cache settings you are telling Joomla that it doesn't necessarily need to recalculate some page content for every page view. Here's a good description http://bit.ly/1sYeXOX . Note that you could go to your menu module > advanced and set your caching preference just for the menu

Comment: somehow i made it work. but i'm not sure about etag. how to use that..?? how should i know the value of etag..??

Comment: good going @gsm11001 , see my edit above about configuring ETags

Comment: thanks for bearing with me and for your support @David. I used this code now, everything looks fine, but i am encountering another problem due to this. My slider images are loading twice before showing. Please see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016471/slider-images-loading-twice-after-cache-control