# slider images loading twice after cache control

Tags: .htaccess, caching, joomla, slider, cache-control

I have use following code in my `.htaccess` file for cache control in my joomla site.

```
########## Begin - ETag Optimization
## This rule will create an ETag for files based only on the modification
## timestamp and their size. 
## Note: It may cause problems on your server and you may need to remove it
FileETag MTime Size
# AddOutputFilterByType is now deprecated by Apache. Use mod_filter in the future.
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript
# Enable expiration control
ExpiresActive On
# Default expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 month"
# CSS and JS expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 1 month"

# Image files expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresByType image/bmp "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jp2 "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/pipeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/tiff "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.wap.wbmp "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.wap.wbxml "now plus 1 month"
```

cache control started working but i am facing a problem.

Now my slider image is loading two times before appearing. once image is loaded then it again loads ( just like refresh ), but other content is loading correctly.

Please help me out.

I am using DJ-ImageSlider extension of joomla. slider does not slide anything, it just show a single image as a banner.

Comment: And you like to have a lot of lines in your `.htaccess`. Because with `ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 month"` no need to add `ExpiresByType xxxx/yyyy "now plus 1 month"` for each type.

Comment: so should i remove the `ExpiresByType` code for all types..??

Comment: It is not necessary to specify those who have the same duration as ExpiresDefault. But you can, if you wish, make such variations by type.

Answer (score 0):

`ETags` are difficult because they take precedence for caching in most browsers. You can change all the headers you want, but if the `ETag` associated with a file is always the same, caching will never work how you expect. In most situations, you should turn your `ETag` headers off.

[Source - David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/yslow-htaccess)

So to unset the `ETag`, you can use the following:

```
Header unset ETag
```

and remove this:

```
FileETag MTime Size
```

Comment: i replaced `FileETag MTime Size` line with `Header unset ETag` but the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to troubleshoot at a distance, but a few ideas you could try.

First make sure you are starting with a clean slate by clearing your browser cache and your Joomla cache, and repeat this step after any changes below.

If problem persists, try going to extensions > module manager > DJ-ImageSlider > Advanced and changing the caching setting.

If still no joy, perhaps play with the cache settings in System > Global Configuration > Cache Settings.

Good luck!

Comment: Tried all these combinations but no success. banner image is loading two times. you can have a look here- http://www.peoplestrong.com/about-us

Comment: Yes, the image seems to appear, then there's a loading gif, then the image comes back. Do you remember what the behaiour was like before you changed the caching in the htaccess file? @gsm11001

Comment: I had put some code to add this `async="async"` code to make all js files load asynchronously. And now this problem is resolved. But another problem has come to my home page. Home pgae started distorting, so for now i removed cache control code from .htaccess. Don't know what to do..  :'( :'(