# load full resource from server

Tags: html, css

when we are referencing our css and html what normally happens is it does not loads the updated files from the server i know there are dozens of solutions on the internet about this issue but what do they do is load a specific file like css etc.what i want to do is to load the whole project from the server every time like css html etc.i found a solution to load css from the server every time a request is sent

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css?d=<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```

but in many cases it happens that it does not auto load the html changes like images etc so i would have to do a `ctrl+f5` to do a reload is there anyway that we can load the whole project from server?

Comment: Have you tried this option IE ->Tools -> Internet Options -> Browsing History (Settings) . Check the option 'Everytime I visit the webpage'

Comment: that's for the client i want a  solution so i can implement it from developer's end

Comment: So you don't really want to reload assets when they change, you want to completely bypass every cache the user might benefit from?

Comment: i want to reload assets on every refresh but when my development is complete then i will remove that portion so that caching will be active again

Comment: Setting [cache-control headers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4485194/3615478) might help.

Comment: Ankit is right: if you only want to disable caching during development the most promising path is adding HTTP headers, something that can typically be accomplished with pure PHP or at web server level.