# Remove default Cache-Control=private from asp.net MVC response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

MVC is adding Cache-Control = private to all of the requests. I tried removing the header using `Response.Headers.Remove("Cache-Control")` with no sucess. How can I make MVC framework not add a default header Cache-Control=private?

Comment: Your response header has to have Cache-Control. Instead of removing it, you can set the value to 'No-cache' or 'No-store'

Comment: See this post for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480304/how-to-set-http-headers-for-cache-control

Comment: I wonder why. It's messing with an Expires header I'm setting as well.