# How to clear downloaded images from cache

Tags: javascript, html, image, caching, memory-leaks

How to clear downloaded images from browser cache?

Here is how i assing new src to `<img>`:

```
img.onload = function () {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = this.width;
            canvas.height = this.height;

            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

            imageSrc = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

            self.$cameraImg.attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageSrc);
        };
img.src = '/camera/image/vehicle/' + id + '/code/' + code + '/cam_no/1/';
```

After many downloads, browsers memory use grow to massive number (> 1gb), after that i get browser crash (Chrome and Firefox).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

Download image as `base64` instead of `image` and dont use `new Image` object and canvas.

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '/camera/image/vehicle/' + self.selected.id + '/code/' + code + '/cam_no/1/',
            data: {},
            success: function (o) {
                if (o) {
                    if (!o.err) {

                        self.$cameraImg.attr('src','');
                        self.$cameraImg.attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + o);

                    } 
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it from the server side. Thus it depends on what tech you are using there. Here are a lot of ideas how: [How to set HTTP headers (for cache-control)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480304/how-to-set-http-headers-for-cache-control). But do not use HTML meta tag, as it is considered as a bad practice for cache control.