# Apache + php + gettext working unstable and translate page partially

Tags: php, apache, gettext

I'm using Apache + php for my project and gettext for translations. All working correct but the i have problem:

In some pages gettext do translations very unstable:

- page full translated
- press "refresh" and the part of translations stay untranslated
- press "refresh" page full translated again.
- after every "refresh" situation the same, sometimes page fully translated and sometimes not

```php
        $directory = PROJECT_ROOT_DIR . "/locale";
        $default_domain = 'messages';
        $locale = 'ua_UK';

        setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale.'.utf8');
        putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale.utf8");
        putenv("LC_ALL=$locale.utf8");

        setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US.utf8');
        putenv("LC_NUMERIC=en_US.utf8");


        bindtextdomain($default_domain, $directory);

        textdomain($default_domain);
```

Version of gettext 1.21

Comment: Just an idea, see if you can desactivate the cache, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4485194/2494754